# Is there an easy way to get the current time difference between the current timezone and UTC in Python?

Tags: python, timezone, timezone-offset

My purpose is simply to output a time zone string like -0700 used in e-mail. Specifically, I want it to reflect the exact time zone, daylight saving included. This means I will get -0700 in California in summer, -0800 in California in winter, and always +0800 in China (no daylight saving).

I find it difficult for two reasons:

1. The Python integer division, unlike in C99 and normal C/C++ implementations, always rounded towards the floor instead of zero. (This matters for calculations involving a time zone like -xx30).
2. struct_time.tm_isdst and time.daylight does not reflect whether daylight saving is in effect.

I ended up with code like the following. It is longer than I expected (esp. for Python!):

```
import math
import time

def my_divide(dividend, divisor):
    if dividend < 0:
        if divisor < 0:
            diff_sign = False
        else:
            diff_sign = True
    else:
        if divisor >= 0:
            diff_sign = False
        else:
            diff_sign = True
    if diff_sign:
        return (int(math.ceil(1.0 * dividend / divisor)), dividend % -divisor)
    else:
        return (int(math.floor(1.0 * dividend / divisor)), dividend % divisor)

def my_timezone():
    gt = time.gmtime()
    lt = time.localtime()
    lt_write = list(lt)
    lt_write[8] = 0  # is_dst
    lt = time.struct_time(lt_write)
    seconds = time.mktime(lt) - time.mktime(gt)
    (hours, minutes) = my_divide(seconds, 3600)
    minutes = abs(minutes) // 60
    return '%(hours)+03d%(minutes)02d' % {'hours': hours, 'minutes': minutes}
```

Anybody having a better implementation?

Comment: use datetime and pytz http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @monkut: for *just* the current machine timezone offset, that is overkill.

Comment: @Martjin: I think I made a mistake in testing about `struct_time`. It is actually the solution I suggest now.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize `time` was dst aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`time.timezone`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.timezone) and [`time.altzone`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.altzone) values.

These provide:

> The offset of the local (non-DST) timezone, in seconds west of UTC (negative in most of Western Europe, positive in the US, zero in the UK)

and

> The offset of the local DST timezone, in seconds west of UTC, if one is defined. This is negative if the local DST timezone is east of UTC (as in Western Europe, including the UK). Only use this if `daylight` is nonzero.

As the documentation for `time.altzone` explains, use the latter when [`time.daylight`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.daylight) is non-zero, but only if the *current* time is in summer time:

```
import time

def my_timezone():
    is_dst = time.daylight and time.localtime().tm_isdst
    offset = time.altzone if is_dst else time.timezone
    westerly = offset > 0
    minutes, seconds = divmod(abs(offset), 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return '{}{:02d}{:02d}'.format('-' if westerly else '+', hours, minutes)
```

Using seconds as a base and `divmod()` there should be no rounding errors here.

For my British summertime location, that gives:

```
>>> my_timezone()
'+0100'
```

Comment: `time.daylight` is a problem (inherited from C). It does not change throughout the year. I.e. you will get +0100 even in winter. But thanks anyway.

Comment: If you replace `time.daylight` with `time.localtime().tm_isdst`, your method actually works. Would you please update your answer so that I can mark it?

Comment: @Martjin: According to the Single Unix Specification, "The tzset() function also sets the external variable daylight to 0 if Daylight Savings Time conversions should never be applied for the time zone in use; otherwise non-zero." http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/tzset.html

Comment: @Martjin: Then we are in agreement? I am actually arguing we should use `struct_time.tm_isdst`, but not using `time.daylight`. Your code currently uses the latter.

Comment: @YongweiWu: and now we come to where the confusion lies and it turns out I was wrong on that point. :-D

Comment: @YongweiWu: indeed, `time.daylight` is the flag that states that the timezone *supports* DST, not if DST is active right now. Will adjust.

Comment: @YongweiWu: again, my apologies; I missed a crucial detail and had an assumption set straight. The correct method to detect if `time.altzone` should be used is to check both `time.daylight` and `time.localtime().tm_isdst`.

Comment: Good. I marked your answer, and deleted some comments that are no longer relevant.

Comment: Your answer still references time.daylight, which might be confusing. Consider revising that too. :-)

Comment: @YongweiWu: well, its use is correct; you only need to look at `tm_isdst` if `time.daylight` is non-zero. It saves you a system call by first checking if the system call is needed at all.

Comment: @Martjin: Interesting note. I guess the performance difference is hard to notice, and the code is slightly more verbose. Good to know your intention still.