# Time of the current day in seconds in Python

Tags: python

I know how to get time of the current day in seconds

```
import time
seconds=time.time() % 86400
```

However the result is valid for UTC.  Is there elegant way to do that for local time?  I am aware I could get that somehow from local time `struct_time`, but it will be rather complicated procedure.  Is there any *elegant* way to do that?

Comment: Add the timezone offset to `time.time()` before getting the modulus.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15971505/8935887

Comment: Can you post some example so that the answer is specific to the problem statement.

Comment: @Barmar The problem is that offset is changing due to summer saving time.

Comment: @BrianTon It is using `datetime` and is rather awkward.

Comment: @abheet22 MWE includes `import time` in the front

Comment: @Pygmalion Use `time.altzone()` when DST is in effect.

Comment: @Pygmalion does that mean you are strictly looking for a solution in `time`, not `datetime` module?

Answer (score 1):

It's not complicated to get it from `struct_time`.

```
t = time.localtime()
secs = 3600 * t.tm_hour + 60 * t.tm_min + t.tm_sec
```

Comment: I guess this is less complicated than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289016/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-current-time-difference-between-the-current-time

Comment: I expected there should be something simpler and seconds are rounded to integer.

Comment: If you want the fraction you can add `math.modf(time.time())[0]`

Comment: Or perhaps add `time.time() % 1`?